# Transferring via Origin: 'Star Wars Battlefront'. Can I resell?

Tags: origin, star-wars-battlefront-2015

I'm a mac user and tried to install the new star wars battlefront, which is Windows only. I purchased the for PC 'download only' disc from EA, which includes only a  code for installation.

I downloaded origin, setup an account, and added the code that I got from EA. Then I just got a screen telling me 'Game only available on Windows' and thought, 'oh, balls'. So now I want to sell the game code on ebay.

[image]

The question is, will another user have a problem installing and playing this game using this code? Is there a way to remove it from my account to allow for it to be used on another user's origin account?

Comment: Yes - I agree that it likely is. Wondering if since the platform achnowedges that it's the wrong version the outcome would be different. I think I'd need to contact origin or EA for a resolution, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and get a refund. See [here](https://www.origin.com/en-au/how-to/great-game-guarantee) for more information. If it's within 7 days of the purchase date you should be good. Since you are outside of that time it may be more difficult for a refund request to be approved. However since you would've never played it at all I'm sure they'll still give you a refund.

That way you can get your money back and the game will be removed from your account. You can then buy the proper version.

[Click here](https://account.origin.com/cp-ui/orderhistory/index?locale=en_AU&env=prod&sourceType=web&gameId=ebisu) and select *Request a refund* to refund the game. You will need to submit a form which will take some time for them to process.

Comment: Given that this question is close to closure, it might be a better bet to post this on the original question page.

Comment: @Timelord64 It wouldn't answer the other question, as the other person has played the game he activated.

Comment: This isn't actually a duplicate question, and this answer would need re-writing to fit the other question.

Comment: Thanks, all. I actually got it for cheap from an EA employee, so I don't know how to go the refund route. I should have known that PC meant windows-only. I haven't played games in a long time. I miss the old days when you could just sell the game.